# Modifying shape of vector asset at runtime (like cut some part from top) to display user progress in Android. Is that possible?

Tags: android, svg, vector, trim, progress

I'd like to **display player progress by using vector asset in Android**. I'd like to use only one vector asset file because 'progress percentage' may vary. For example it can be very different, like 8%, 51%, etc.

**When** I had plain colored background I used additional rectangular layer same color as background to hide part of SVG accordingly to progress, but now I can't - started using nice images as a background.

**Please see** pictures below to understand what I try to achieve:

[image: 20% progress - SVG cut by 80%]

[image: 40% progress - SVG cut by 60%]

[image: 10% progress - original .SVG]

A were reading this https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-androids-vector-image-format-vectordrawable-ab09e41d5c68 , searched on Google , on stackOverflow - but still no answer.

Guys, do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: this is some kind of image view and your svg is set to its src right? if so check out ClipDrawable. as name tells us you can clip some parts of drawable.

Comment: Yes, Bacho, exactly. In 'xml' layout I assigned my vector asset as <ImageView ... app:srcCompat="@drawable/brain_fill" ... />

Comment: Hej, Bacho, thanks a lot. I've allready implemented solution to my code thanks to your advise of using ClipDrawable!!

Comment: Glad I managed to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/** @IntRange(from=0,to=10000)
 *  0 means hidden 10000 means totally visible*/
fun clipDrawable(level: Int) {
    if (drawable is ClipDrawable){
        drawable.level = level
    } else {
        val clippedDrawable = ClipDrawable(drawable, Gravity.TOP, HORIZONTAL)
        setImageDrawable(clippedDrawable)
        (drawable as? ClipDrawable)?.level = level
    }
}
```

you can create your custom image view and add this method there, or modify it a bit and add it inside of your fragment/activity

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bacho Kurtanidze advise I've already solved my problem. I will explain here what I've done for future visitors:

**1.** Read carefully official ClipDrawable documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable

and this tutorial: 
https://programmer.group/how-to-use-clipdrawable-to-realize-imageview-picture-switching-animation.html
There's everything needed to implement ClipDrawable, although text is not 100% clear.

**2.** Placed my vector asset into separate 'clip_brain_fill.xml' like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:drawable="@drawable/brain_fill"/>
```

**3.** Assigned new 'clip drawable' to ImageView that were holding 'brin_fill.xml; asset before:

...

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/brain_fill_iv"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/brain_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/brain_height"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clip_brain_fill" />
```

...

**4.** Now level of clipping can be set from java code like so:

```
ImageView brainFillIV = findViewById(R.id.brain_fill_iv);

ClipDrawable clipBrainFill = (ClipDrawable) brainFillIV.getDrawable();

clipBrainFill.setLevel((int) (percents * 100));
```